# Transparent layer of text over an image

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="photo" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="My Image" height="240" width="240" />
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I create a layer on top of the image where I can write some text? The layer should have transparency, be aligned to bottom and having a size of 240x60?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this you need : http://jsfiddle.net/EgLKV/357/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make the image a background?

```
<div class="photo" style="float:left; margin:2px">
    <a href="#" style="background:url('images/image.jpg');
          width:240px; height:240px; display:inline-block;">Your text here</a>
</div>
```

The `display:inline-block` allows you to apply width and height to an otherwise inline element, but here you might even want to just use `display:block` since it's the only child of the container.

EDIT: You can even put more containers in it, something like this:

```
<div class="photo" style="float:left; margin:2px">
    <a href="#" style="background:url('images/image.jpg'); position:relative;
          width:240px; height:240px; display:block;">
        <span style="display:block;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
              background:white;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);">Your text here</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I get partial transparency of the text background?

Answer (score 1):

Text blocks over images.   Website and demo as follows:

http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it like with an image container like that :

**Html**

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="path/to/image" />
    <p class="caption">My text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
    position:relative;
}

.caption {
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;

}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/ByGQg/) !

Answer (score 1):

**Markup**

```
<div class="figure-container">
    <img src="http://ipadwallsdepot.com/detail/solid-color_00015061.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
    <span class="figure-label">FIG 1.1: Caption Text Here</span>
</div>

<div class="figure-container">
    <img src="http://ipadwallsdepot.com/detail/solid-color_00015061.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
    <span class="figure-label">FIG 1.2: Another Caption Here</span>
</div>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
.figure-container 
{
    position: relative;  
    display: inline-block;
}

.figure-label
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: White
}
```

I created a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AbBKx/ showing how to absolutely position a child element (label) relative to a parent container.